# How to play audio in Cocos2D javascript

Tags: html, audio

Is it right? It doesn't work.

```
var snd = new Audio('/bgm/1.mp3') //the path is [project dir]/src/resources/bgm/1.mp3
snd.play();
```

Answer (score 1):

var snd = new Audio('/**jah**/assets/bgm/1.mp3') //the path is [project dir]/src/resources/bgm/1.mp3
snd.load();
snd.play();

try the above changes it will work in debug mode

Comment: this was almost right. 

var audioElement = new Audio( "/__jah__/assets/resources/snd/" + filename );

for the folder 

/src/resources/snd

did the trick for me. when I doubt have a look at the resources panel in your browser, all the files in the /src folder appear there.